VMware -> Broadcom: how to renew/purchase a VMware Workstaion Pro license?
Since May 5, 2024 Broadcom shut down the self-purchase licensure portal for VMware customers.  Click on 'Login' in upper-right here: https://www.vmware.com/ takes you to this 'site-maintenance' dead end.
Hours of digging and I must ask "How does one renew a VMware Workstation Pro license now that Broadcom owns it?"
I have called Broadcom support and even they don't know.

Does this answer your question? Can you help me with my software licensing issue?

Thanks @vidarlo.  Turns out that Broadcom has made VMware free.  :-)  I hope that means support will actually improve with more users able to answer questions.  Certainly solves the question of how I pay for VMware Workdation.  -RCHF

Turns out that Broadcom as of my writing this email has made VMware Workstation free.  This eliminates the need for paid support to get updates.  -RCHF

Only for non-commercial personal use...
